# Converting xml values to rows in SQL Server like oracle XAMLTABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with XML values in this format

```
id| xml_record 
--+------------
1 | xmlvalue
2 | xmlvalue
```

The xml value is in this format

```
<record>
    <c2>date1</c2>
    <c2 m="2">date2</c2>
    <c2 m="3">date3</c2>
    <c3>number1</c3>
    <c3 m="2">number2</c3>
    <c3 m="3">number3</c3>
</record>
```

I need a query to generate this:

```
id | pmt_pos | pmt_date | pmt_number
---+---------+----------+-----------
1  |  1      | date1    | number1
1  |  2      | date2    | number2
1  |  3      | date3    | number3
```

In Oracle I use the following query successfully to generate two virtual tables with the id's, dates and number and join them on the id and the position of every row:

```
SELECT t1.id
    ,t1.pmt_pos
    ,t1.pmt_date
    ,t2.pmt_number
FROM (
    SELECT t.id
        ,xt.pmt_date
        ,nvl(xt.pmt_pos, 1) pmt_pos
    FROM myTable t
        ,XMLTABLE('/row/c2' passing t.xml_record columns pmt_date VARCHAR(8) path '/', pmt_pos VARCHAR(3) path '@m') xt
    ) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT t.id
        ,xt.pmt_number
        ,nvl(xt.pmt_pos, 1) pmt_pos
    FROM myTable t
        ,XMLTABLE('/row/c34' passing t.xml_record columns pmt_number VARCHAR(50) path '/', pmt_pos VARCHAR(3) path '@m') xt
    ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    AND t1.pmt_pos = t2.pmt_pos
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Is there an equivalent function to Oracle xmltable in SQL or another way to achieve the same results?

Comment: Not exactly like XMLTABLE, no. Have you tried reading the docs on [nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type), [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type) and [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) yet?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no XMLTABLE exact equivalent, the [nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) method on xml data types can achieve similar results like. For the above example it would work like this:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML = '
<record>
    <c2>date1</c2>
    <c2 m="2">date2</c2>
    <c2 m="3">date3</c2>
    <c3>number1</c3>
    <c3 m="2">number2</c3>
    <c3 m="3">number3</c3>
</record>'

DECLARE @t TABLE  (ID int, XMLRECORD XML)

INSERT INTO @t values (1,@xml)

 SELECT 
 
ID
,isnull(t1.value('(@m)[1]','nvarchar(200)'),1) AS pmt_pos
,t1.query('.').value('/','nvarchar(30)') pymt_date
,t2.query('.').value('/','nvarchar(30)') pmt_number


FROM @t x
cross APPLY x.XMLRECORD.nodes('/record/c2') AS T1(t1)   
cross APPLY x.XMLRECORD.nodes('/record/c3') AS T2(t2)  

where isnull(t1.value('(@m)[1]','nvarchar(200)'),1)  = isnull(t2.value('(@m)[1]','nvarchar(200)'),1)
```